# LD giving strange error and not finding an existing file when using ARM gcc

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm

This is the command line executed by my Makefile:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc bubblesort.c -O0 -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -Wl, -T ../boot_and_link/linker.ld -l ../boot_and_link/startup.o
```

As I understand it, it should compile bubblesort.c for a CortexM0 and then the linker should you use linker.ld as a linker script and should also link startup.o with the output of compiling bubblesort.c.

I get two errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.8/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: cannot find -l../boot_and_link/startup.o
```

The first one I don't understand. ld tells me it cannot find : which makes no sense and makes me think there an error in my linker script.

The second error is just weird because my linker file is in the exact same location and it finds it and yes I've checked the file's names and they are the same.

Just in case I'm including my linker script on account of it being short and that I wrote it myself (first time) and I'm learning how to write them.

```
MEMORY
{
  rom   :       ORIGIN = 0x00000000,    LENGTH = 8K
  ram   :       ORIGIN = 0x20004000,    LENGTH = 16K
  stack :       ORIGIN = 0x20003FFF,    LENGTH = 16K
}

SECTIONS
{
    .nvic_vector : { } >rom /*The vector table that is initialized in c code*/

    .text : 
    {
        *(.text)      
        /*_DATAI_BEGIN = .;*/
    } >rom

    .data : 
    {
    _DATA_LOAD = LOADADDR(.data);   /*The absolute address of the data section*/
        _DATA_BEGIN = .;        /*From where to begin the copy to RAM*/
        *(.data)      
        . = ALIGN(4);           /*Make sure the byte boundary is correctly aligned*/
        _DATA_END = .;          /*Where to end the copy to RAM*/
    } >ram AT >rom

    .bss :
    {
        _BSS_BEGIN = .;         /* Zero-filled run time allocate data memory */
        *(.bss)       
        _BSS_END = .;
    } > ram 

    .heap :
    {
        _HEAP = .;
    } > ram

    .stack :
    {
    . += LENGTH(stack);
    . = ALIGN(4);
        _STACKTOP = .;  /* The top of the stack is the last available section of memory*/
    } >stack

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove the space in `--Wl, -T`.

Comment: this parameter: '-l ../boot_and_link/startup.o'  is telling the linker to look for a library named 'startup.o', I.E. the -l should not be used when indicating an object file to include in the link.

Comment: the linker file needs to allocate room, in rom, for the vector table, not just an address..  so the code should define the vector table, similar to defining a .text code segment or .data segment, and that should be referenced within the {} of the .nvec_vector statement

Comment: the linker does not llink files that are not amongst its' parameters.  so the bubblesort.o file should be listed (probably after) the startup.c file.  Note:  in general, it is better to have separate statements for the compile steps and for the the link step.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I managed to realized that I needed to add the startup.o as a parameter for the linker and to remove the space. And this made me move forward. However I will separate the compiling and the linking into two lines

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question?

Comment: Hummm no. However the answer provided was not exactly addressing my mistake so I did not mark it as correct. The correct answer would have been to eliminate an extra space and pass the startup.o as a parameter to the linker scirpt. However I did follow your advice and ended up separating the linking and compilation processes

Comment: Well, then post an answer yourself. Otherwise this won't help anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main problem was this line:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc bubblesort.c -O0 -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -Wl, -T ../boot_and_link/linker.ld -l ../boot_and_link/startup.o
```

This was wrong as the -l switched is used to link with a library and not to just point another object file which was my intention. You need to specify all files for linking as normal ordinary arguments to the linker. The way I ended up doing this was simply (taking Beryllium's advice) separating the compilation and linking into two steps and using two separate calls. Here are the commands that are run by my makefile:

```
<-------------------- Compiling C Source Files -------------------->                                                                                                                                                      
arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 -c -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -g bubblesort.c -o bubblesort.o                                                                                                                                          
<-------------------- Linking files -------------------->                                                                                                                                                                 
arm-none-eabi-ld bubblesort.o ../boot_and_link/startup.o -nostartfiles -T ../boot_and_link/linker.ld -o bubblesort.elf
```

This worked.

PD: The first error (wher it says it cannot find : No such file or directory) had to to with incorrect spacing in the gcc call. However as I changed it, I cannot exactly recall where it was.

Answer (score 0):

You could separate compilation and linking, then it's easier to see

- flags common both for compiler and linker
- flags only for one of these

If you have `main.c` and `startup.c`, compilation should look like this:

> arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -Os -std=gnu99 -o startup.o -c startup.c
>
> arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -Os -std=gnu99 -o main.o -c main.c

As for linking

> arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -nostartfiles -T rom.ld -o main.elf startup.o main.o -lc -lm

---

If you want it in a single line:

> arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -Os -std=gnu99 -nostartfiles -T rom.ld -o main.elf startup.c main.c